# My code for this subtree max sum problem is currently not passing the test case listed below. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

For whatever reason, my code for my total function looks right but my subtree sum function isn't working with this.

```
#total function: returns sum of leaves of a binary tree

def total(t):
  if isinstance(t, int) or isinstance(t, float):
    return t
  else:
    return sum(total(i) for i in t)

#max_subtree_total: returns maximum sum of subtree within binary tree

def max_subtree_total(t):
    if isinstance(t, tuple):
      add = total(t)
      for i in t:
         subtotal = max_subtree_total(i)
      return max(subtotal, add)
    else:
      return t
```

Currently, not passing this test case:

```
check_equal(max_subtree_total((-3, -4)), -3)
```

```
#check_equal function

def check_equal(x, y, msg=None):
    if x == y:
        if msg is None:
            print("Success")
        else:
            print(msg, ": Success")
    else:
        if msg is None:
            print("Error:")
        else:
            print("Error in", msg, ":")
        print("    Your answer was:", x)
        print("    Correct answer: ", y)
    assert x == y, "%r and %r are different" % (x, y)
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? What happens when you run your code? Does it give an error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the output? What should it be instead? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: edited with test case function and test case currently failing

Comment: You will need to debug your code. You can add `print()` statements or use a graphical debugger. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: pretty hard to analyse since I get hung up on the logical faults. The `max(subtotal, add)` is always going to be `add` since the subtree can't contain more than the whole tree. The loop `for i in t: ...` makes no sense at all: you are discarding all but the last result anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is in the `max_subtree_total` function. This is what you do:

```
  for i in t:
     subtotal = max_subtree_total(i)
  return max(subtotal, add)
```

Basically you compute the max between the second child and the head, without considering the first child. What you should do instead is this:

```
subtotal = max(max_subtree_total(t[0]), max_subtree_total(t[1]))
return max(subtotal, add)
```

This adjustment will make your test pass.